# Intercepting fifo

Tags: linux, bash, named-pipes

I have two named pipes which are used for communication between an app and a service.

Basically the App is a GUI that takes input from the user and writes data to named pip lets call it `out_fifo`. The service reads that data and does some other stuffs and after it finishes processing, it writes the result to a named pipe lets call it `in_fifo`. At this point the App reads data from `in_fifo` ..

By any chance, is it possible to intercept/proxy/read the written data from both pipes? I mean can I read the data being passed to both pipes without interrupting the app and the service?

What I've tried to read the incoming data from the service:

```
#!/bin/bash    
in_data="in_fifo"
while :; do
    while true
    do
        if read -r line; then
            echo "Data: $line"
        fi
    done <"$in_data"
done
```

But I see nothing from the shell nor does the App continue running. The app hangs waiting for data

Answer (score 0):

strace can help. Look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46502533/13876104

**EDIT**: You can always add an additional set of fifo's and an application to proxy your communication but that would mean rewiring your original apps. But that is an overhead which is best avoided if the only reason you want to do this is to monitor data for debugging purpose for example.

Comment: Thx, but `strace` is not an option

Answer (score 0):

No; like its name should reveal, a FIFO is simply first in, first out. There is no way to reorder stuff or read without consuming the stream.

What you *could* do is create a proxy which reads from one set of FIFOs and writes the same data back to another set, and then rewire the consumer to use the second set instead of the first.

Comment: Actually the script I posted in the question is missing one line (I removed it), which it does the exact thing you mentioned `echo "$line" >> out_fifo` right after printing the line to the screen. But for some reasons the app hangs and I see no output in the terminal.